# Unable to position the search box

Tags: html, css

I want to position my search box such that it looks like : [image]

But, my CSS is yielding this : [image]

My CSS :

```
body{
background-color: #DBDBDB;
}

.headerMenu{

background-image: url(../img/headerMenu.png);
height: 50px;
border-top: 0px;
border-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
width: 100%
}

#wrapper{
background-image: url(../img/headerMenu.png);
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: auto;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;

}

.logo{
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 110px;
width: 80px;
}
.logo img{

width: 150px;
height: 38px;
}

.search-box{
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
bottom: 20px;
left: 80px;
}

#search input[type="text"]{
background:  url("../img/search_white.png") no-repeat 350px 6px #ffffff;
font: Arial;
outline: none;
border: none;
font: bold 12px;
width: 350px;
padding-left: 10px;
 }
#search input[type="text"]:focus {
background:  url("../img/search_dark.png") no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
color: #6a6f75;
width: 350px;
}
```

What's wrong ? I just can't move the search box. Seems like its stuck. I tried playing with the position metrics but I can't find the way out.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>iFriendify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="headerMenu">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                    <img src="./img/logo.png"/>
            </div class="search-box">
                <form action="search.php" method="GET" id="search">
                    <input type="text" name="q" size="60" placeholder="Search! "/>

                </form> 
            <div>



            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Your search box is absolutely positioned in relation with its closest parent element that has a position defined.

Comment: Also, you are missing an opening `div` tag that's mixed up with a closing one. `<img src="./img/logo.png"/></div class="search-box">`.

Answer (score 1):

Set `position: relative` in .headerMenu or using `float:left` on .logo

Answer (score 0):

Change position of menuheader to relative.
When parent element have static position then child element's absolute position will not work

You can also do that without using positions remove position and add float left on logo.

Comment: Use float:left; on logo

Comment: Yes. I managed to move it left but I still align it with the logo.

Comment: It is stuck there. I just to move it 25px from left and 10px from top and align in plane with the logo.

Comment: Remove position:absolute;